# Consent Order from UK Home Office

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

I have got a consent order from home office, saying that they will review my application and I have asked to withdraw my judicial review.

My question is after I sign the consent order and then my application is denied what can I do?

Comment: If you're seeking judicial review and are contemplating signing anything, let alone an agreement to withdraw your application, this really seems like a question only a lawyer can answer. You're asking for legal advice.

Comment: Which group shoud I post that on

Comment: There is a law.stackexchange.com, but I don't believe this would be on-topic there either. You're asking for personalized legal advice. Only a qualified lawyer can give you that. Strangers on the internet do not have the experience or the information necessary to give specific advice about how to proceed in an ongoing court case. If this is in connection with an asylum claim, I'd recommend you find a local organization that assists asylum applicants.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for legal advice, which can only be given by a qualified lawyer.

Comment: If you have reached that stage of the judicial process without personal  guidance then it's already problematic beyond what the internet can do. You shouldn't be on the net.  Close voting as opinion-based.